# Processing: KeyPressed and displaying new set of Data (using same key)?

Tags: processing

I was wondering how I would go about getting a different set of data to print every time I press the same key for KeyPressed in Processing. The data being displayed is from an imported file so the code for what I'm doing is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

PImage cityMap;
FileInputStream in;
int Year=0;

void setup()
{
size(500,500);
cityMap=loadImage("cityMap.png");
background(cityMap);
}

void draw()
{
//EMPTY

}
void keyPressed() {

if(key==CODED)
{
if(keyCode==RIGHT)
{

  //2015 
  String fif[]= loadStrings("2015data.txt");
  for (int i=1; i<fif.length;i++)
  {
  Scanner sc= new Scanner(fif[i]);
  int xValue= sc.nextInt();
  int yValue= sc.nextInt();
  int pixelX= locX2PixX(xValue);
  int pixelY= locY2PixY(yValue);
  stroke(200,200,250);
  point(pixelX,pixelY); 
  }

  //2016
  String six[]= loadStrings("2016data.txt");
  if(
  for (int i=1; i<six.length;i++)
  {
  Scanner sc= new Scanner(six[i]);
  int xValue= sc.nextInt();
  int yValue= sc.nextInt();
  int pixelX2= locX2PixX(xValue);
  int pixelY2= locY2PixY(yValue);
  stroke(250,200,250);
  point(pixelX2,pixelY2);
  }
   //2017
  String seven[]= loadStrings("2017data.txt");
  for (int i=1; i<seven.length;i++)
  {
  Scanner sc= new Scanner(seven[i]);
  int xValue= sc.nextInt();
  int yValue= sc.nextInt();
  int pixelX3= locX2PixX(xValue);
  int pixelY3= locY2PixY(yValue);
  stroke(20,200,250);
  point(pixelX3,pixelY3); 
  }
  }
  }
  }

  int locX2(int locationX)
  {

  return((int)((6*locationX)-8));

  }

  int locY2(int locationY)

  {

  return((int)(8*locationY+8));
  }
```

I managed to get the code to run minus that one feature.
I think I have most of the logic down, I'm just trying to figure out to have this show only one set of the data at a time and then the next one after I press the same key again. I was thinking I may need some type of if statement that could maybe use my year variable?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want to do, but this sounds like you want to keep "state" in a variable so you know you've done something (i.e, handled a button press already) so the next time you get the same event you can handle it differently.

Comment: I wanted to make it so that the first time I hit the right arrow key, the data under 2015 loads . Then the data under 2016 loads once the right key is pressed again (but without the 2015 data showing at the same time etc... But is what your saying is to make another variable and update it each time I press the right arrow key? Would I need to use an if statement to do so? I'm still a bit confused but I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

(I don't know that much about Processing, but it's silly to chat in comments about general purpose computer programming...)

It sounds like you need to maintain "state", which is a fancy way of saying a variable where you store information about if you have done something before, and what that thing is.

First, how many states do you care about? It sounds like you have two distinct options, so if you add the initial state, this technically makes three (but for only two valid states we can ignore that for now). Ok, so your startup code (constructor or initializer, whatever is typical for Processing) will set a variable of some sort to a known start value.

How to do this is up to you. It could be a String or an int or something advanced like an `enum`. The idea is that this is a testable, settable, persistent chunk of data that you know the meaning of.

Every time you handle the "event" of a button being pushed you do two things:

1. Test the state you initialized earlier and make a decision. In the initial state you want to load "2015" data. Ok. So do that.
2. Change the variable holding the state so it is in the "next" state. In the 2015 state we want to change that to 2016 so we are ready for the next button event we handle.

A simple example would be to create an `int` called `dataState` or something. In `setup` set this to 2015. In your button handler have a `switch` or `if` statement that checks for all possible values `dataState` can be, and runs the appropriate code for that state.  e.g., if it is set to 2015 it will do whatever you need it to do for 2015, but at the end it should set the `dataState` to 2016 so that the next time through it does the 2016 branch.

It is up to you what the 2016 branch does to this state. You can reset it to 2015 or continue on to 2017, if your code needs to have that functionality.

Some comments:

- You'll notice that your code for processing 2015 data is almost the same as the code that processes 2016 data. This is an opportunity to use a function or method that accepts a filename and does some work based on that, and then sets the state to the "next" state.
- Once you do this, then your logic in the button handler becomes a nice short and understandable set of `if` ... `else if` statements that simply call the appropriate function for that state. This makes it easy to add, say, 2017 processing. Code *always* grows features so it's good to plan ahead for that.
- Once you get really good at this, you'll start thinking about "state models" and then before you know it you'll want to have your state managed as a class or `enum` with a big `switch` statement that drives the whole works. This is a *very* common pattern with embedded, event driven code that Processing supports.

Answer (score 1):

keep track of your year in a variable and change it when the key is pressed. Something like this

```
    //start off one less than first desired year 
    int Year=2014;

    void keyPressed() { 
        if(key==CODED) { 
        if(keyCode==RIGHT) { 
            //increment year
            Year = Year+1;
            //Clamp year between 2015 and 2017
            Year= Math.max(2015, Math.min(2017, Year));
            String yr[]= loadStrings(Year +"data.txt"); 
                for (int i=1; i<yr.length;i++) { 
                    Scanner sc= new Scanner(yr[i]); 
                    int xValue= sc.nextInt(); 
                    int yValue= sc.nextInt(); 
                    int pixelX= locX2PixX(xValue);
                    int pixelY= locY2PixY(yValue);
                    stroke(200,200,250); 
                    point(pixelX,pixelY); 
                }
            }
        }
   }
```